# How to import two values from html to my SQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to import the values of emailaddress and fullname from html into my SQL table.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <title>Julian's Newsletter</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


        <link href="newsletter.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Newsletter</h1>
    <form action="formsubmit.php" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Subscribe to my Newsletter</h2>
    <p>Subscribe to my newsletter to recieve recent news, a specialy curated product list, and the Product of the Month.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="fullname" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" name="emailaddress" required>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="subscribe"> Monthly Newsletter
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
  </div>
</form>
    </body>
```

And here is my PHP so far. I am a beginner and I have very little knowledge of PHP.

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$emailaddress = "emailaddress";
$fullname = "fullname";
$dbname = "email_windowsisslow_com";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $fullname, $emailaddress);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO emaillist (emailaddress, fullname)
    VALUES ('', '')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

I am new to Stack Overflow and I do not assume that anyone will actually write the code for me. I need help understanding what is written, and how to write the code to perform the action I require of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I would suggest you must use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection. 

 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO emaillist (emailaddress, fullname)
        VALUES (:emailaddress , :fullname)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':emailaddress ', $emailaddress );
    $stmt->bindParam(':fullname ', $fullname );
    $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP file change the two lines:

```
$emailaddress = "emailaddress";
$fullname = "fullname";
```

To

```
$emailaddress = $_POST["emailaddress"];
$fullname = $_POST["fullname"];
```

And add to your insert statement

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO emaillist (emailaddress, fullname) VALUES ({$emailaddress}, {$fullname})";
```